# Installing jupyter error "nothing provides openssl >=1.1.1,<1.1.2.0a0 needed by python-2.7.15-h9bab390_2"

Tags: installation, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install jupyter but I am encountering some error. When I run:

`conda install -c anaconda jupyter`

The resolver just takes forever and doesn't really get anywhere. When I instead try it with mamba:

`mamba install -c anaconda jupyter`

I get the following output:

```
Looking for: ['jupyter']

anaconda/linux-64                                           Using cache
anaconda/noarch                                             Using cache
bioconda/linux-64                                           Using cache
bioconda/noarch                                             Using cache
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/r/linux-64                                               No change
pkgs/main/linux-64                                            No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.9.*


Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides openssl >=1.1.1,<1.1.2.0a0 needed by python-2.7.15-h9bab390_2
```

The error says that "nothing provides openssl >=1.1.1,<1.1.2.0a0 needed by python-2.7.15-h9bab390_2". However, when I enter in 'conda list', I can see the following:

`openssl                   1.1.1s               h0b41bf4_1    conda-forge`

I'm pretty sure that 1.1.1 is >= 1.1.1, so what I have installed should meet the requirement, but it's not. When I type 'which openssl', I get:

`~/.conda/envs/workingENV/bin/openssl`

For python --version I get:

`Python 3.9.15`

I can confirm that typing 'conda update conda' and 'condate update --all' beforehand does not resolve this. I don't know if it's related, but when I type in one of these, I also get this warning (although the warning doesn't impede the completion of the commands execution):

```
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda/linux-64::m4-1.4.18-h4e445db_0
  - defaults/linux-64::m4-1.4.18-h4e445dbdone
```

Comment: What happens if you try Conda Forge only? E.g., `mamba install -c conda-forge jupyter`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was trying to follow the suggestion at https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter which specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `openssl` indicates it came from Conda Forge. Conda Forge is a standalone channel and trying to mix in packages from Anaconda channels can lead to unexpected behavior. Try sticking to just the `conda-forge` channel, e.g.,

```bash
mamba install -c conda-forge jupyter
```

Note that a better setup is to have Jupyter (plus `nb_conda_kernels`) installed in a dedicated environment and only install `ipykernel` in the kernel environments.