# Jupyter Notebook does not see new kernel with anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new to Anaconda. I have a previous history with Jupyter Notebook and none of it was good. I'm taking a course on ML and the author glosses over a lot of how to set up anaconda, jupyter, etc.

The goal seemed to be to set up a new kernel that runs python and tensorflow. This seems to have worked correctly and the new kernel is running Anaconda.

[image]

If I click on this kernel and open a jupyter notebook - either by the terminal or by directly - the Jupyter Notebook seems to recognize the new kernel.

[image]

However, any effort to open up a file results in a 500 error. Opening a Jupyter Notebook with the base kernel does still work, but it doesn't show the new kernel.

I have no idea what is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: You are glossing over a lot here, too. What did you follow to make the new environment? Something like [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/get-your-conda-environment-to-show-in-jupyter-notebooks-the-easy-way-17010b76e874)? What are you using to activate them and launch Jupyter there? Does your set-up involve using `nb_conda_kernels`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089315/8508004), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook), and [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3311#issuecomment-406740348)?